# How to Resize and Position Buttons in PySide?

Tags: python, qt, button, resize, pyside

I am writing an application using PySide and have added two buttons two it. However, when I run the program the buttons scale the length of the window which is not what I want. What I want is the button to be of a small size and positioned to the right. How do you do this? Is there any method I could use?

Comment: Best method - is to read qt documentation about layouts and widgets (especially sizing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what layout you've used or which you want to use, maybe this will help:

Using Box Layout:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python2.7
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from PySide import QtGui

class Sample(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Sample, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 800, 600)
        self.setWindowTitle('Sample')

        btn1 = QtGui.QPushButton("Button 1")

        hbox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.addStretch(1)
        hbox.addWidget(btn1)

        self.setLayout(hbox)
        self.show()

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Sample()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```